# How to the same Interface to different QT Classes

Tags: c++, qt, inheritance, design-patterns

#### Goal

I want to benchmark some drawing libraries and gather diagnostics. I thought of implementing in each benchmark the same interface and then instantiating different classes in the main window.

#### The Challenge

The problem is that some benchmarks use `QWidget` and other `QOpenGLWidget`. So even if I implement the same functionality I can not use it, without dynamic casting to each possible instance.

#### What I tried so far

My first thought was to create an interface and use virtual multiple inheritance. But that doesn't seem to work and I am not sure if that's even the right solution.

I also thought of the *Composite Pattern* or *Adapter Pattern*, but seem some problems, as I want to override some functions of `QWidget` like `resizeEvent` in each benchmark. Of course I could duplicate that code or put it into some non-member function. But maybe there is something more elegant?

#### QWidgets Addin

```cpp
class BenchmarkAddin : virtual public QWidget {
public:
    BenchmarkAddin() {
        connect(&timer_, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(update()));
    }

    double get_fps() {
        // use frames_ and time to estimate fps
    }

    void count_frame() {
        ++frames_;
    }
    
    void set_parameters(int param1_) {
        param1_;
    }

protected:
    void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent* event) override {
        init();
    }

    virtual void init() = 0;

    int param1_;
private:
    int frames_;
    QTimer timer_;
}
```

#### Raster Benchmark

```cpp
class RasterBenchmark : public BenchmarkAddin {
protected:
    void init() override {
        // create buffers
    }

    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event) override {
        // do drawing using param1_
        count_frame();
    }
}
```

#### OpenGL benchmark

```cpp
class OpenGLBenchmark : virtual public QOpenGLWidget, public BenchmarkAddin {
protected:
    void paintGL() override {
        // do GL drawing using param1_
        count_frame();
    }
}
```

#### Main Window Example Usage

```cpp
BenchmarkAddin *widget; 
if (benchmark == "raster") {
    widget = new RasterBenchmark(this);
else
    widget = new OpenGLBenchmark(this);

widget.set_parameters(100);

...

std::cout << widget.get_fps() << std::endl;
```

Obviously this doesn't work, as `QOpenGLWidget` doesn't use virtual inheritance for `QWidget`. Also there is a problem with Qt's object meta system.

### Question:

Any idea how I could implement an interface that is both accessible within a subclass of `QWidget` and `QOpenGLWidget`?

Comment: What are you trying to benchmark?

Comment: Some 2d render libraries like `skia`, `blend2d`, `qt`, ...

Comment: Sure, but benchmark what, the runtime? Because for that, you do not need this complexity, just a RAII timer class?

Comment: I want to benchmark the redraw speed (fps) for each backend. Also I want to capture the differences between CPU vs OpenGL backends. So I don't see any other way than an application level benchmark. I already did some micro-benchmarking to pre-select the toolkits.

Comment: I would go for instrumentation. I had an answer for that before, do not want to duplicate it.